# Unable to install inet framework for OMNeT++ 5.6.1

Tags: omnet++, inet

Getting error

> Installing project has encountered a problem. Cannot download project description from https://models.omnetpp.org/descriptors/omnetpp-5.6/inet.xml.

Kindly help in installing inet framework.

Answer (score 0):

That should work now. That is caused by the firewall rejecting your request. However this is really a question regarding the infrastructure, more suitable for the OMNeT++ mailing list.